# accumulating event listeners

Tags: javascript

I could try and write what happens, but I thought it would be easier to show it. The thing is, if I could explain what exactly happens, I could probably fix it.

what I would like:
1..click record -> show recording button bright red
2. click bright red record button -> stop recording + show play button
3. click play button -> log playedNotes + change playbutton to bright red + change text to stop
4. click stop button -> log stopped
5. click record again -> repeat the steps above

thing is, the play button wont change into stop en bright red and the console logs stopped along with it.

```js
const $record = document.getElementById('record');
const $playBtn = document.getElementById('playBack');
let playedNotes = ["G", "B"], recording = false, playingRecordedPart = false;


  $record.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(!recording){
      recording = true;
      playingRecordedPart = false;
      $playBtn.style.display = "none";
      $record.classList.toggle('recording');
    } else {
      recording = false;
      $record.classList.toggle('recording');
      if(playedNotes.length !== 0){
        $playBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
        playPart();
      } else {
        console.log('nothing was recorded');
      }
      
    }
  })

  function playPart(){
    // my mistake: $playBtn.addEventListener which multiply each 
    // time playPart() is being fired. changed to onclick 
    $playBtn.onclick = function(){
      if(!playingRecordedPart){
        playingRecordedPart = true;
        $playBtn.innerText = "STOP";
        $playBtn.classList.add('playing')
        console.log(playedNotes)
      } else {
        playingRecordedPart = false;
        $playBtn.innerText = "PLAY";
        $playBtn.classList.remove('playing')
        console.log('stpped')
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
.record-btn {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #370617;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.record-btn:hover, .play-btn:hover {
  background:#6A040F;
}

.recording, .play-btn.playing {
  background:#D00000;
}

.recording:hover, .playing:hover {
  background:#D00000;
}

.play-btn {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #370617;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 0 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="record-section">
    <div id="record" class="record-btn">RECORD</div>  
    <div id="playBack" class="play-btn" style="display:none;">PLAY</div> </div>
```

Comment: Running `playPart();` adds more and more event listeners. So you get more and more running on click. If there is an even number of event listeners then Play changes to Stop then back to Play again because each event listener will do a change.

Comment: Thanks Vlaz, do I understand correctly if I would append the startbutton dynamicly each time I stop recording? and remove it from the dom when recording again?

Comment: You're currently just showing and hiding it. You do not need to add any more event listeners every time. Just add the event listener for `$playBtn` once and you will not have to deal with multiple firing at once.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful. That fixied it.

Comment: please change the title, so that people with similar problems can find it via web search

Comment: You are right! any suggestion for a proper title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new event listeners each time you click the `RECORD` button after the first click. You need to extract the `click` event listener out of the `playPart` function and remove that function (and its references) altogether. The below code snippet shows this example.

```js
const $record = document.getElementById('record');
const $playBtn = document.getElementById('playBack');
let playedNotes = ["G", "B"],
  recording = false,
  playingRecordedPart = false;


$record.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!recording) {
    recording = true;
    playingRecordedPart = false;
    $playBtn.style.display = "none";
    $record.classList.toggle('recording');
  } else {
    recording = false;
    $record.classList.toggle('recording');
    if (playedNotes.length !== 0) {
      $playBtn.style.display = "inline-block";
    } else {
      console.log('nothing was recorded');
    }

  }
})
$playBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (!playingRecordedPart) {
    playingRecordedPart = true;
    $playBtn.innerText = "STOP";
    $playBtn.classList.add('playing')
    console.log(playedNotes)
  } else {
    playingRecordedPart = false;
    $playBtn.innerText = "PLAY";
    $playBtn.classList.remove('playing')
    console.log('stpped')
  }
});
```

```css
.record-btn {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #370617;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.record-btn:hover,
.play-btn:hover {
  background: #6A040F;
}

.recording,
.play-btn.playing {
  background: #D00000;
}

.recording:hover,
.playing:hover {
  background: #D00000;
}

.play-btn {
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 12px;
  background: #370617;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
  margin: 0 0 0 11px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="record-section">
  <div id="record" class="record-btn">RECORD</div>
  <div id="playBack" class="play-btn">PLAY</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Less code. Better. Thanks!